# Disable a default key binding in GNU screen

Tags: emacs, gnu-screen

I keep accidentally switching the audio bell to the visual bell by turning on by hitting C-a C-g.

In emacs C-g is used stop or abort the current command or process.  If I already hit a C-a and then decide I want to abort everything, I start spamming C-g.

Unfortunately, this toggles the bell style between audio and visual.

I would like C-a C-g to abort the current command or process in screen, so that when I hit C-g I abort all processes and commands in both screen and emacs.

What would I need to add to change this key binding?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title, [read the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Bind.html#Bind), and add this to your `.screenrc`:

```
bind ^g
```

Comment: Oh, that also does what is in the text, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use both screen and emacs regularly, you can save yourself a lot of aggravation by changing the screen escape character.  For example, add something like this to your `.screenrc`:

```
escape ^Zz
```

This changes the prefix for all screen keystrokes from <kbd>C-a</kbd> to <kbd>C-z</kbd>.  <kbd>C-z</kbd> is a good choice for two reasons.  First, it's not mapped to anything I regularly use in emacs.  But it also works for me since <kbd>C-z C-d</kbd> detachs from a screen session, which is one of the more common things I do in screen sessions, and I associate it with suspending a process with <kbd>C-z</kbd>.

Comment: For future noobs: be careful what you bind here; keys like 'ctrl-g' conflict with other sequences.